# MySQL For Each condition with specific values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm trying to use a call a stored procedure with a set of values that i'm receiving from another query and i would like to know on how i can i call another procedure using the value from a query . here is my code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `temp`(IN u_id int)
BEGIN

#below query will give me all the u_id values that i need to use(ex : 2,8,9) 
Declare cur cursor for select r_id from temp.usr_rl where u_id in (u_id);

#below i would like to use the u_id values and run the below procedure in a loop for each value in u_id
open cur;
repeat
   fetch cur into a;
    if not done then
      call get_r(a);
    end if;
until done end repeat;    

close cur;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

That would cause you huge performance hit since you are using cursor to process every record and calling another procedure. Thus you are actually doubling the effect. Instead, fetch and store all the values in a `Temporary Table` using `CTAS` like below and access that temporary table from within your procedure `call get_r` for whatever further processing you are doing.

```
create temporary table myTemp 
as select r_id from temp.usr_rl where u_id = u_id;
```